# if $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3-px^2+qx-r=0$, find the value of $(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)$

Tags: roots

> If $a,b,c$ are the roots of $ x^3-px^2+qx-r=0$, find the value of $(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b):$
>
> A) $p^3 -8r$
>
> B) $4pq-p^3$
>
> C) $4pq-p^3-8r$
>
> D) $4pq-8r$

Solution:

$$a+b+c= p$$

$$ab+bc+ca= q$$

$$abc= r$$

Using above we get:

$$(p-2a)(p-2b)(p-2c)$$

Comment: Hint: Expand the last expression in the post. We get $p^3-2p^2(a+b+c)+4p(ab+bc+ca)-8abc$.

Comment: Another hint: This is $8f(p/2)$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$a+b-c=a+b+c-2c=p-2c=y\iff c=\dfrac{p-y}2 $

As $c$ is a root of the given equation, set the value of $c$ to form a cubic equation in $y$ on simplification.

Finally use Vieta's formula